# elasticsearch-rails with mogodb - undefind method as_indexed_json for article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Hi I am trying to use elasticsearch-rails in my Rails + mongo application.
I am using mapping block for indexes but when I try to import my record to elasticsearch by

```
Article.import
```

Its giving me error undefined method as_indexed_json for Article

And If I create any article & comments for that it create index for all attributes of article model in elasticsearch server but it not creating index for nested comments attributes which I mentioned in mapping block

I tried same with sqlite3 database and everything is working fine but it not working with mongodb database

Gemfile

```
..................... .....  
..................... .....  
gem "elasticsearch", :git => "git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby.git"     
gem "elasticsearch-model", :git => "git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git"
gem "elasticsearch-rails", :git => "git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git"
```

config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: 'http://localhost:9200'
```

app/models/article.rb

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  field :title, :type => String
  field :content, :type => String
  field :published_on, :type => Date
  field :abstract, :type => String

  has_many :comments

  index_name "name_of_elasticsearch"

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 0 } do
    mapping do
      indexes :_id, :as => "_id.to_s", :index => "not_analyzed"
      indexes :title, :type => "string", :index => "not_analyzed"
      indexes :content, :type => "string", :index => "not_analyzed"
      indexes :published_on, :type => "date"

      indexes :comments, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :body, analyzer: 'snowball'
        indexes :stars
        indexes :pick
        indexes :user, analyzer: 'keyword'
        indexes :user_location, type: 'multi_field' do
          indexes :user_location
          indexes :raw, analyzer: 'keyword'
        end
      end 
   end 
 end
end
```

app/models/comments.rb

```
class Comment
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Timestamps

   field :body, :type => String
   field :pick, :type => String
   field :stars, :type => Date
   field :user, :type => String
   field :user_location, :type => String

   belongs_to article
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `as_indexed_json` method explicitly:

```
  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    as_json()
  end
```

It helped in my case with exactly the same issue.